# How can you shorten repetitive if/else statements?

Tags: objective-c

How can you simplify this code? It gets very lengthy and is extremely repetitive, with so many null checks.

```
    id data;

    data = [dictionary objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
    if ([data isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        self.firstName = @"";
    }
    else{
        self.firstName = (NSString *)data;
    }

    data = [dictionary objectForKey:@"MiddleName"];
    if ([data isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        self.middleName = @"";
    }
    else{
        self.middleName = (NSString *)data;
    }

    data = [dictionary objectForKey:@"LastName"];
    if ([data isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        self.lastName = @"";
    }
    else{
        self.lastName = (NSString *)data;
    }

    ...
```

Ideally I would want to put all the variables in an array of sorts, and just loop through and apply the null check and assignment to all of them. But you can't exactly store variables in an array. What is the best way to shorten this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap each of those calls into one method.

```
- (NSString *)stringFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *) forKey:(NSString *)key 
{
    id data = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    if ([data isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        return = (NSString *)data;
    } else {
        return @"";
    }
}
```

Then call the method three times.

```
self.firstName = [self stringFromDictionary:dictionary forKey:@"FirstName"];
self.middleName = [self stringFromDictionary:dictionary forKey:@"MiddleName"];
self.lastName = [self stringFromDictionary:dictionary forKey:@"LastName"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ternary operator to shorten your code

```
self.firstName = [data isEqual:[NSNull null]] ? @"" : (NSString *)data;
```

Comment: How does this deal with NSNull?

Comment: That is some seriously illegible code. I wouldn't recommend this because this kind of thing is hard to maintain.

Comment: @Almo: that's an opinion, I personally don't find the ternary operator hard to read or mantain. It obviously depends on what you put inside but this seems to be quite simple.